# google app engine local server does not run on chrome/firefox

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome

When I create an application in google app engine and open the application (http:localhost:8080) in safari it works fine. But when I open in chrome or fire fox it does not run (http:localhost:8080) and gives the following page.

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error Message</TITLE>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<STYLE id=L_10061_1>A {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #005a80; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
A:hover {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #0d3372; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
TD {
    FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
TD.titleBorder {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 0px solid; COLOR: #955319; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; TEXT-ALIGN: left
}
TD.titleBorderx {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 0px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 8px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 1px solid; COLOR: #978c79; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma; HEIGHT: 35px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b87a; TEXT-ALIGN: left
}
.TitleDescription {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
SPAN.explain {
    FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #934225
}
SPAN.TryThings {
    FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; COLOR: #934225
}
.TryList {
    MARGIN-TOP: 5px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR: black; FONT-FAMILY: tahoma
}
.X {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #955319 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #955319 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; BORDER-LEFT: #955319 1px solid; COLOR: #7b3807; BORDER-BOTTOM: #955319 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d1c2b4
}
.adminList {
    MARGIN-TOP: 2px
}
</STYLE>
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2800.1170" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>
<BODY bgColor=#f3f3ed>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD class=titleBorderx width=30>
      <TABLE height=25 cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=0 width=25 bgColor=black>
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD id=L_10061_x class=x valign=middle align=center>X</TD>
        </TR>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
    </TD>
    <TD class=titleBorder id=L_10061_2>Network Access Message:<SPAN class=TitleDescription> The page cannot be displayed</SPAN> </TD>
  </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>

<TABLE id=spacer>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD height=10></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<TABLE width=400>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap width=25></TD>
    <TD width=400><SPAN class=explain><ID id=L_10061_3><B>Explanation:</B></ID></SPAN><ID id=L_10061_4> The Web server refused the connection. </ID><BR><BR>
    <B><SPAN class=tryThings><ID id=L_10061_5><B>Try the following:</B></ID></SPAN></B> 
      <UL class=TryList>
        <LI id=L_10061_6><B>Refresh page:</B> Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. The timeout could have occurred due to Internet congestion.
<LI id=L_10061_7><B>Check spelling:</B> Check that the Web page address is spelled correctly. The address may have been mistyped.
<LI id=L_10061_8><B>Access from a link:</B> If there is a link to the page you are looking for, try accessing the page from that link.
<LI id=L_10061_9><B>Contact website:</B> You may want to contact the website administrator to make sure the Web page still exists. You can do this by using the e-mail address or phone number listed on the website home page.

      </UL>
<ID id=L_10061_10>If you are still not able to view the requested page, try contacting your administrator or Helpdesk.</ID> <BR><BR>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>

<TABLE id=spacer><TBODY><TR><TD height=15></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>

<TABLE width=400>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD noWrap width=25></TD>
    <TD width=400 id=L_10061_11><B>Technical Information (for support personnel)</B> 
      <UL class=adminList>
        <LI id=L_10061_12>Error Code 10061: Connection refused
<LI id=L_10061_13>Background: The server you are attempting to access has refused the connection with the gateway. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the server.
<LI id=L_10061_14>Date: 11/8/2012 1:19:34 PM [GMT]
<LI id=L_10061_15>Server: NBS-TMGPTCL.Cdocs.local
<LI id=L_10061_16>Source: Remote server

      </UL>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 4):

It says you are trying to connect to :

```
NBS-TMGPTCL.Cdocs.local
```

and not

```
http:localhost:8080
```

in any case, use

```
http//:localhost:8080
```